# Issue with Test Method, covering 70% instead of 100%

Tags: apex, unit-test

```
Apex Class:
public class Nanostuffs_clsConvertLead
{
public PageReference convert()
{
try
{
String id = ApexPages.currentpage().getParameters().get('id');

Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
lc.setLeadId(id);
lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);

LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);

Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
if(lcr.isSuccess())
{
String cId = lcr.getAccountId();
PageReference redirect = new PageReference('/' + cId);
redirect.setredirect(true);
return redirect;
}
}
catch(Exception e)
{
ApexPages.addMessages(e);
}
return null;
}
}

TestClass:
@istest
public class Nanostuffs_clsConvertLead_Test
{
static testmethod void Nanostuffs_clsConvertLead_Test()
{
Nanostuffs_clsConvertLead nt=new Nanostuffs_clsConvertLead();
nt.Convert();
}
}
```

TestClass Not Covered:
[image]

Comment: Hello these many people understand the question except  you guys not understand see every time putting on hold means its disgusting

Answer (score 1):

Lead Conversion has failed so underlying lines are not covered(Red) as you can see that the catch block gets covered(Blue).

The reason could be anything -

- Validation rule on Lead/Account/Contact.
- Id in setLeadId is null

Kindly apply
 
`system.debug('>>>>>>>'+e.getMessage());`
in catch statement to display the error in debug logs and then fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Lead record in your test class before you try to convert "nothing" in this scenario.

```
Lead lead = new Lead();
lead.FirstName = 'Test';
// set all the required fields
insert lead;
```

Then you need to set the current page in your test method:

```
Test.setCurrentPage(Page.YOURPAGENAME);
```

Then set the Id parameter in the URL to the newly created Lead in the test method:

```
Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', lead.Id);
```

and finally run your method:

```
Nanostuffs_clsConvertLead nt=new Nanostuffs_clsConvertLead();
nt.Convert();
```

Comment: Hi Bachovski What Ever you said i have tried still it is not getting same as 70 percent code coverage it is showing..............!if u good at test class please copy it in your org just try it once because i am trying since from 3 days i am not getting so please once try it

Comment: In your `convert` method, inside the catch block, can you please add `system.debug(e.getMessage());` line and check your debug log when you run the test class? That will give you indication on what went wrong and why the lead is not getting successfully converted.